# Qt C++ delegate при нажатии на ячейку пишутся дополнительные нули

Tags: c++, qt, tableview, делегаты

Привет всем. Есть TableView, сделал для него делегат, переопределил методы, все работает, но с QDoubleSpinBox проблема одна, для него я задаю количество максимальных знаков, пусть это будет 9. Но Проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю на ячейку где он используется то вместо того, чтобы мне вывести 555.5555 он выводит мне 555.555500000, слышал о переопределении метода в QDoubleSpinBox **textFromValue** на отсечение не нужных нулей, но как его правильно переопределить в моём коде то? есть у кого мысли? Вот мой код

delegate.h

```
#ifndef DELEGATE_H
#define DELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class Delegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
Delegate(QObject *parent = 0);

virtual QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
virtual void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
virtual void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;

};

#endif // DELEGATE_H
```

delegate.cpp

```
#include "delegate.h"

#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <QDateTimeEdit>
#include <QTimeEdit>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtCore>

Delegate::Delegate(QObject * parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{

}

QWidget *Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
 Q_UNUSED(option);

 qDebug() << index.data().type();

 if (index.data().type() == QVariant::Double)
 {
    QDoubleSpinBox * editor = new QDoubleSpinBox(parent);
    editor->setDecimals(15);
    editor->setMinimum(LONG_MIN);
    editor->setMaximum(LONG_MAX);
    return editor;
 }
 else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::String)
 {
    QLineEdit * editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
    return editor;
 }
 else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::Int)
 {
    QSpinBox * editor = new QSpinBox(parent);
    editor->setMinimum(LONG_MIN);
    editor->setMaximum(LONG_MAX);
    return editor;
 }
 else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::DateTime)
 {
    QDateTimeEdit * editor = new QDateTimeEdit(parent);
    return editor;
 }

}

void Delegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
if(index.data().type() == QVariant::Double)
{
    QDoubleSpinBox *sbox = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    if (sbox != 0)
    {
        sbox->setValue(index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toDouble());
    }
}
else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::String)
{
    QLineEdit *le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    if (le != 0)
    {
        le->setText(index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString());
    }
}
else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::Int)
{
    QSpinBox * sbox = qobject_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
    if (sbox != 0)
    {
        sbox->setValue(index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toInt());
    }
}
else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::DateTime)
{
    QDateTimeEdit * dte = qobject_cast<QDateTimeEdit*>(editor);
    if (dte != 0)
    {
        dte->setDateTime(index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toDateTime());
    }
}

}

void Delegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
// setModelData - отвечает за сохранение изменений в ячейке

if(index.data().type() == QVariant::Double)
{
    QDoubleSpinBox * sbox = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(editor);
    if (sbox != 0)
    {
        model->setData(index, sbox->value(), Qt::EditRole);
    }
}
else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::String)
{
    QLineEdit * le = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    if (le != 0)
    {
        model->setData(index, le->text(), Qt::EditRole);
    }
}
else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::Int)
{
    QSpinBox * sbox = qobject_cast<QSpinBox*>(editor);
    if (sbox != 0)
    {
        model->setData(index, sbox->value(), Qt::EditRole);
    }
}
else if (index.data().type() == QVariant::DateTime)
{
    QDateTimeEdit * dte = qobject_cast<QDateTimeEdit*>(editor);
    if (dte != 0)
    {
        model->setData(index, dte->dateTime(), Qt::EditRole);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `editor->setDecimals(15);` я правильно понял, что вы хотите выводить числа с точностью 15 знаков после запятой?

Comment: да правильно, число 15 задал для тестирования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вам поможет метод [setDecimals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#decimals-prop). Но если отвечать непосредственно на вопрос о  [textFromValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdoublespinbox.html#textFromValue) то можно поступить так:

```
class DoubleSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox{
public:
    DoubleSpinBox(QWidget *parent) : 
        QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
    {}
    QString textFromValue(double value) const{
         //Тут любой способ преобразования числа в строку
         //Можно так
         return locale().toString(value, 'f', 2); 
         //Или так
         return QString::number(value, 'f', 2); 
         //Или можно попробовать так, если вам не нравятся именно нули
         QString result = QDoubleSpinBox::textFromValue(value);
         result.remove(QRegExp("0+$"));
         return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: спасибо, разобрался.